# How to customize both DIV and TABLE form widgets without duplicating code in symfony

Tags: forms, twig, symfony

Trying to customize Symfony form rendering, I have the following in my config.yml

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```

The `form/fields.html.twig` contains a customized number widget:

```
{%- block number_widget -%}
    <input type="text" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} value="{{ value|filter }}" />
{%- endblock number_widget -%}
```

Everything works fine as long as I use default form layout (div). However, if I want the form to have table layout, I try to add something like this in the template:

```
{% form_theme 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}
```

The form gets displayed as table, but then my customized number_widget is no longer customized!

I have also tried:

```
{% form_theme 'my_cystom_theme.html.twig' %}
```

with `my_cystom_theme.html.twig` containing:

```
{% use 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}
```

Did not help.

Question:

Is there a way to make application wide customization of a widget for both div and table layout forms without duplicating the code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use a custom tempalte with multiple 'use' blocks:

1. create custom table-layout form, for example `form/table_layout.html.twig`, such as:

   ```
   {# original table layout template #}
   {% use 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}

   {# our custom field widgets #}
   {% use 'form/fields.html.twig' %}

   {# define more custom widgets for table layout here #}
   ```
2. In order to render a table layout form with our custom widgets, use this in the template:

   ```
   {# form_theme 'form/table_layout.html.twig' #}
   ```
3. Do the same for div layout. Custom widgets from `form/fields.html.twig` will be used in both table and div layouts without duplicating the code.